# Storing SharePoint Lists and SharePoint Sites

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2007

Here's a question for everyone, I has a list of sharepoint sites that is put into a dropdownbox, I would like to enumerate through each site and bring back a list of the lists that are in, and store them separately so that they can be process later in the program. So I attempt to do this here, and they are added to collections, now where I am stick is I am wondering how would I associate the two collections together because obviously when it creates an entry for lets mysp.com/PR with lists Documents, Images, & Articles. How would you suggest I associate those two so when it retrieve the sites, and the list it knows which belong to which? If Im not clear please let me know and Ill try to clear it up a little.

Thank You

```
for (int j = 0; j < MyListofSitesDropDown.Items.Count; j++)
{
    if (MyListofSitesDropDown.Items[j].Value.ToString() != "AllSites")
    {
         //REMOVE UNIMPORTANT CODE HERE

        if (MyListofSitesDropDown.Items[j].Value.ToString() != "INVALID")
        {
            sitecollection1.Add((string)MyListofSitesDropDown.Items[j].Value.ToString());
        }
    }
}
foreach (string siteitem in allsitesalllists)
{
    ListsDropDownBox.Items.Add(new ListItem(siteitem,"SITE" + sitecounter));
    sitecounter++;

    using (SPWeb oWebsite = new SPSite(siteitem).OpenWeb()) //Open SP Web
    {
        SPListCollection collList = oWebsite.Lists; //Open Lists

        foreach (SPList oList in collList)
        //For Each List Execute this
        {
            if (!oList.Hidden)
            {
               listcollection.Add((string))oList.Title)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would load all your information in generic lists of custom .NET objects (eg : `List<SharePointSite> availableSites` and within your object `SharePointSite` you have a property that return a list of `SharePointList` (of course from that specific site)

Once everything is loaded (and in cache to avoid the heavy work once again), you can easily bind your dropdown lists to your generic lists and have cascading lists if needed

Note that when you're loading your object, you could store the guid, url and title for both site and list, that way, you have all available lists that you can reuse later on and you can easily identify them by their guid (the url will definitively be unique if you take the full url, not the server relative url but it's handier to find back your items based on a guid, it feels less dirty ;-))